# Django How can I cache properly to reuse data?(with using django-mptt package and redis module)

Tags: python, django, caching

I am making kind of dynamic menu. when you click menu on the top, it show sub menu on the left side. I searched with keyword 'dynamic menu' from stackoverflow and google. I got idea to build that kind of menu. I made it like below.

1) render data(menu list) in context to template by custom context processor.

2) using custom template tag which is provided by django-mptt package.

3) show top menu in base template.

4) move to another template to show sub menu according to what top menu you click

I made custom context_processor to use menu in context in every template.

context_processor.py

```
from manager.models import Menu

def menu(request):
    menu_list = list(Menu.objects.all())
    return {'menu':menu_list}
```

template.py(example)

```
{% load mptt_tags %}

<nav id="{{ menu_id }}" class="tree-menu">
    <ul>
        {% recursetree menu %}
            <li class="menu
                {% if node.is_root_node %}root{% endif %}
                {% if node.is_child_node %}child{% endif %}
                {% if node.is_leaf_node %}leaf{% endif %}

                {% if current_menu in node.get_descendants %}open{% else %}closed{% endif %}
            ">
                <a href="?{{ node.menu_name }}={{ node.pk }}">{{ node.menu_name }}</a>
                {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                    <ul class="children">
                        {{ children }}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
                {% if node.items and node.items.exists %}
                    <ul class="items">
                        {% for item in node.items.all %}
                            {% if item_template %}
                                {% include item_template %}
                            {% else %}
                                {% include "menu/tree-item.html" %}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endrecursetree %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

mptt_tags.py

```
@register.tag
def recursetree(parser, token):
    """
    Iterates over the nodes in the tree, and renders the contained block for each node.
    This tag will recursively render children into the template variable {{ children }}.
    Only one database query is required (children are cached for the whole tree)

    Usage:
            <ul>
                {% recursetree nodes %}
                    <li>
                        {{ node.name }}
                        {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                            <ul>
                                {{ children }}
                            </ul>
                        {% endif %}
                    </li>
                {% endrecursetree %}
            </ul>
    """
    bits = token.contents.split()
    if len(bits) != 2:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError(_('%s tag requires a queryset') % bits[0])

    queryset_var = template.Variable(bits[1])

    template_nodes = parser.parse(('endrecursetree',))
    parser.delete_first_token()

    return RecurseTreeNode(template_nodes, queryset_var)
```

**My Question**

1. If you see django manual about [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/), it says that "Each QuerySet contains a cache to minimize database access". It is obvious that, if you query same data in certain rule, it doesn't seem hit database again but return result from cache. Then I am querying Menu.objects.all() in custom context processor. This result(menu_list = Menu.objects.all()) will be in context every time, you can use menu data on every template repeately. **So does it reuse the result from cache without hitting database again?**
2. If menu_list = Menu.objects.all() in custom context processor hit database every time whenever template load this menu list, **Does it work in this way to reuse menu data from cache without hitting database everytime**?

context_processors.py

```
from manager.models import Menu
from django.core.cache import cache

def menu(request):

    menu_list = cache.get_or_set('menu_list', list(Menu.objects.all()))

    return {'menu':menu_list, 'redis':"Food"}
```

3. Lastly, I don't know if there are many people using django-mptt package. I guess just a few people have experience using it in person. It says "Only one database query is required (children are cached for the whole tree)" **so does it mean if I use django-mptt package and get menu from it on template, it automatically cache its data?**

Well, I am not clear about django cache system.

It would be really appreciate if you can give me answer and insight for my questions. Thanks for reading!

Comment: You could simply turn on logging in your database so that every time a query is issued it will be logged. Then call your view. If the cache works the query for your menu will only be issued once.

Comment: Oh. Good tip. Thank you!